# Loading font native-base error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm getting the error: `You started loading 'Roboto_medium', but used it before it finished loading` when using native base.

[image]

I've followed the instructions in the official page.

To create react native app I'm using `create-react-native-app`.

App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

async componentWillMount() {
  await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
  'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
  'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
  'Ionicons': require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
 });
}

 render() {
   return (
    <Container>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />

    <Button>
      <Text>
        Button
      </Text>
    </Button>

    <ListaItens />
    </Container>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you need to wait till the fonts get loaded. You can do something like this

```
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { Container, Button, text, ListItem, Text } from "native-base";
import Expo from "expo";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: true };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
    });
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <Expo.AppLoading />;
    }
    return (
      <Container>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />

        <Button>
          <Text>Button</Text>
        </Button>

        <ListItem />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This new code for expo SDK 35 which was modified from @akhil xavier 's answer

First install expo-font

```
expo install 'expo-font'
```

here is the App.js

```
import React from "react";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { Root } from "native-base";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: true };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/build/vendor/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
    });
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator />;
    }
    return (
      <Root>
       <RootPage /> // starter component (i.e. nav)
      </Root>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution that works for me is below. The error I had was that I imported Font as (Fonts) but while calling it failed to notice the 's'. Fixed it by making sure the import name is similar to what you call the loadAsync to. You need to have 'expo-font' installed in your project for it to work

```
import React from "react";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import MealsNavigator from "./navigation/MealsNavigator";


const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    "open-sans": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
    "open-sans-bold": require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf")
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);
  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
        onError={err => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }
  return <MealsNavigator />;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Glad to see someone else is also following Max's courses. In my case I forgot to return Font.loadAsync() inside of fetchFonts.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is having this issue with the 'MaterialIcons' font family, I had a similar problem and found following this solution worked:

https://javascriptrambling.blogspot.com.au/2018/03/expo-icon-fonts-with-react-native-and.html

You basically need to:

1. Install the fonts (using npm install)
2. Do a Font.loadAsync on the fonts in your componentWillMount() function.
3. Remember to mark the componentWillMount() function as async
4. The conditionally display either as 'loading' or with the view depending on the state of a 'loaded' flag.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { AppLoading, Font } from 'expo';

import FontAwesome  
  from './node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts/FontAwesome.ttf';

import MaterialIcons  
  from './node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        FontAwesome,
        MaterialIcons
      });
      this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error loading icon fonts', error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>My App</Text>
        <Avatar
          small
          rounded
          icon={{ name: 'add' }}
        /> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way which I use to load Fonts in my project. I feel this more abstracted as compared to all the other answers.

What you need to do is create a custom hook to Load fonts

You can do it something like this

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located. Then inside `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js`

Inside `useFonts.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

export default useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
    Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
    Ionicons: require('@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
  });
```

Now in your `App.js` write like this

```js
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  // This function will start the fontLoading
  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  // This is a check to ensure fonts get loaded
  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  // If fonts are successfully loaded then show the rest of your App
  return (
    <Container>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />

      <Button>
        <Text>Button</Text>
      </Button>

      <ListaItens />
    </Container>
  );
}
```